# Execute npm script using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute npm script using js

Have following in package.json

```
"script": {
   "commit": "git commit -m {dynamic message}"
}
```

And in the JS i want to reach to this script, execute it and send dynamic message to it

Comment: And what is your problem when you try to do that?

Comment: Idk how to execute it from the JS function thats the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will run commands it could be any command

```js
const { execSync } = require('child_process')
execSync("some-command")
```

Comment: I need to execute commit from the JS file programatically not from the CLI

Comment: Look at this API https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options you can run commands through this